# Regarding storing input into a string, and using cout to display it

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

I am writing a program that will request a user input of INT, and store it in an array of [10]. I want to be able to get the user to select the option DISPLAY and see all the data within the array. I just cannot figure it out, here is what I have so far :

```
case 2 : {
                 int SamtW;
                 cout << " Please enter how much you would like to withdraw "<< endl;
                 cin >> SamtW;
                 sa.doWithdraw(SamtW);
                 break;
             }
```

and here is the function that is being called above :

```
int saving:: doWithdraw(int amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     last10withdraws[amount];
    }
    if (amount > 1)
    {
    setBalanceW(amount);
    }
    else {
        cout << " ERROR. Number must be greater then zero. " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I believe this will put the user input into the string last10withdraws. I then want the user to be able to call this function :

```
string saving::display()
{
    last10withdraws[10];
    return 0;
}
```

and this will hopefully display the contents of the array. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop in `doWithdraw`? It doesn't make sense at it is now.

Comment: I wanted it to place the parameter of int amount into the array last10withdraws.

Comment: That is not how it is done but that can wait. **where you want to put it? in to the whole array? I mean in all 10 places in the array?**

Comment: No I need it to place it in slot 0. and then when they call the function again it will be placed into slot 1. and then slot 2. and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last10withdraws[10];
```

This doesn't do anything. This takes the value of the 11th element of the array (which doesn't exist) and then throws it away.

Similarly this:

```
 last10withdraws[amount];
```

Take the value of an element of `last10withdraws` and throws it away. It doesn't assign it any value or store it anywhere.

I think you want:

```
int saving:: doWithdraw(int amount)
{
    if (amount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 9; i != 0; i--)
        { // move the 9 elements we're keeping up one
            last10withdraws[i] = last10withdraws[i-1];
        }
        last10withdraws[0] = amount; // add the latest
        setBalanceW(amount);  // process the withdraw
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " ERROR. Number must be greater then zero. " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK From your comments:

First you need one additional variable in your `saving` called something like `nr_of_withdraws`. It will keep track of how many `withdraws` has been made. And it should be assigned zero when the class is constructed.

Then every time you insert in to `last10withdraws` you increment `nr_of_withdraws`. If `nr_of_withdraws` is greater than 9 then your array is full and you need to do something about it. So...

---

```
// Constructor.
saving::saving {
    nr_of_withdraws = 0;
}
```

---

```
// doWithdraw
int saving:: doWithdraw(int amount)
{
    // See if you have space
    if(nr_of_withdraws > 9)
       cout << "last10withdraws are done. Slow down."
       return 0;
    }
    // These lines. oh thy are needed.
    last10withdraws[nr_of_withdraws] = amount;
    nr_of_withdraws++;

    if (amount > 1)
    {
        setBalanceW(amount);
    }
    else {
        cout << " ERROR. Number must be greater then zero. " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay I went ahead and put that in my code but I am still having issues with calling the display function . How would I be able to call it and get it to display all the data in the array?